# Access to XAMPP from Bluestacks

Tags: xampp, localhost, bluestacks

How can I open my localhost (in Windows 8 with XAMPP) webpage, from a browser installed in Bluestacks App Player?

Thank you

Comment: Hello, @geovanny. Could you please accept my answer, if its works for you?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Type `Win+R` (To open Run)
Open cmd
type `ipconfig`
You will get IP address in Ipv4 Address field.
Note: The IP will reset on connection reset/restart

OR 
You can access localhost from Bluestacks by `10.0.2.2`

Comment: Thanks it works. But I can't see `ip` by `ipconfig` however I can access with 10.0.2.2

Answer (score 2):

Follow the tutorial on this link: [HOW TO ACCESS TO XAMPP FROM BLUESTACKS](https://www.techeduca.com/how-to-access-to-xampp-from-bluestacks/).

It will guide you explicitly on how to install loopback adapter on Windows and configure your IP.

**Step 1: Install Microsoft Loopback Adapter in Network Connection Manager**

*To install the Loopback adapter in Windows Vista, 7, 8, Server 2008 or Server 2012:*

- Click Start, then type `cmd` in the search box.
  When cmd.exe appears, right-click it and choose *Run as administrator*.
- In the command prompt, type `hdwwiz.exe` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
  Click *Next*.
- Select *Install the hardware that I manually select from a list (Advanced)*, then click *Next*.
- Select *Network adapters*, then click *Next*.
- Select *Microsoft* as the manufacturer, select *Microsoft Loopback Adapter* as the adapter, then click *Next*.
- Select *Next* to confirm the installation.
- Select *Finish* to complete the installation.

*To configure the newly created adapter:*

- Click Start > Control Panel > Network Connections.
- Select the newly created connection (named Local Area Connection #, where # is its order number).
- Right-click on the selected connection and choose *Properties* from the menu.
- Confirm that *Microsoft Loopback Adapter* or *Microsoft Loopback Adapter #* is displayed in the Connect Using: field.
  If it is not, return to step 2 and retry properties for another adapter.
- Deselect everything except *Internet Protocol (TCP/IP)*.
- Select *Internet Protocol (TCP/IP)*, and click *Properties* to open Internet Protocol (TCP/IP) Properties.
  Select *Use the following IP address*. Fill in the *IP address* and *Subnet mask* fields.
  Example: 192.168.1.10, 255.255.255.0
- Click *Advanced* to open Advanced TCP/IP Settings.
- Switch to *WINS* and select Disable *NetBIOS over TCP/IP*.
- Click *OK** to close Advanced TCP/IP Settings.
- Click *OK* to close the Internet Protocol (TCP/IP) Properties.
  (Windows XP only) Deselect Notify me when this connection has limited or no connectivity to remove the connection warning icon from the system notification area.
- Click *OK* to close the connection properties.

You will find screenshots in the tutorial from the above mentioned link. It worked for me sure it helps.

Comment: cannot find "Microsoft Loopback Adapter" in list , after selecting microsoft

Comment: Please look at this carefully https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/259c7ef2-3770-4212-8fca-c58936979851/how-to-install-microsoft-loopback-adapter

Answer (score 1):

use your local ip ex:192.168.1.101

Comment: This does not seem to work when using a port number as well. I always get "The request hostname is invalid".

Comment: 192.168.1.10 <<< is what you mean

Answer (score -1):

Install windows loopback adapter as a virtual ethernt. Set the IP addrs.